# MissingMemberException in json.loads()

Tags: ironpython

I am using `IronPython 2.6.10920.0 on .NET 4.0.30319.1` as a part of HFSS field simulation software under linux. And I am having a strange problem with the `json` module:

```
>>>import json
>>>print json.dumps('foo')
'"foo"'
>>>print json.loads('"foo"')
MissingMemberException: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'scanner'
```

What could be the cause? And how can I get it to work?

**UPD:** when I wrap the code above into `try: .. except .., e: print e`, I get this output:

```
System.MissingMemberException: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'scanner'
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) object:CallSite.Target  (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext)
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3[System.Object,IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext,System.Object].Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.RunInstructions (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What does he want to tell me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the json module worked in 2.6. Try [upgrading to 2.7](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/90087) if you can, where json does work.